# Mount Error on opening

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, ntfs, fstab

I haven't used ubuntu for long time so I forgot most of command and how to fix issues.
I have Dual boot , Windows 8 and ubuntu latest version I use ubuntu for my work and Windows for gaming and other stuff.

Unable to access “Main [G-E]”

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/semary/Main [G-E]: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/semary/Main [G-E]"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

**I already turn off fast startup on widows 8**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: @JacobVlijm did u read my post it already off

Comment: No offense, but as I said, the link describes also *other possible causes*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jacob Vlijm for sharing link with me to help me and other having this problem

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdxy`   (where sdxy is partition u want to mount)

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable Fast Boot in Windows
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

Comment: i already turned it off but still